# Reading a .dat file

Tags: vb.net

I have a file I am trying to read and disply results into a text box. The file has no extension, but it is a 'data' file per the website (www.checkfiletype.com).

Here is a screen shot of how the file looks in a online reader, it looks like hex?
[image]

I have tried a stream reader, and gives nothing in results. Last method I tried was a BinaryReader, that I have never used before. The results from this is a "0" into the text box. Given that I have never used the BinaryReader function, I am sure I did something wrong with it.

```
Using reader As New BinaryReader(File.Open("C:\Users\jefhill\Desktop\CMOSDATA", FileMode.Open))
        Dim pos As Integer = 0
        Dim length As Integer = reader.BaseStream.Length
        While pos < length
            ' Read the integer.
            Dim value As Integer = reader.ReadInt32()
            ' Write to screen.
            TextBox1.Text = value
            ' Add length of integer in bytes to position.
            pos += 4
        End While
    End Using
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I tried using a basic StreamReader. With this, nothing happens, as in no errors, just puts nothing(blank) into the textbox.

```
Dim file As String = "C:\Users\jefhill\Desktop\CMOSDATA"
    Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(file)
    TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
    reader.Close()
```

Comment: Have you tried with the DataFileReader :) I am joking. What you are showing in the snapshot is what you can get when reading it as text (e.g., with `StreamReader`). If the file is encrypted in any way (e.g., Excel file, PDF, executable, an image, etc.), you would have to know the encryption to determine the best way to read it. A .data extension doesn't say anything (other than perhaps you shouldn't be trying to read this file because it is most likely meant for internal purposes of certain application and doesn't seem to be what you are looking for).

Comment: @varocarbas Thanks for the reply, I just tried using a few verations of StreamReader, both gave same results of, nothing. When I say nothing, I mean no errors, just puts nothing into the textbox. Updated top post with most recent code I tried.

Comment: As said, it all depends upon the used encryption; even the text you see is encrypted (e.g., to be displayed in occidental characters). I recommend you to not waste time in all this: either you know exactly the format of the given file or you might be spending long time to get nothing.

Comment: Alright, cool, thanks for the help and advise!

Comment: Not that it has anything to do with your question, but your code using the `BinaryReader` only gives you one number because you keep _setting_ the text every time. You gotta _append_ each number to it. Change this: `TextBox1.Text = value` to this: `TextBox1.Text &= value`.

Answer (score 0):

The file is not a text file, and cannot be directly displayed in a TextBox. You will need to find the format of the file and convert it to text in order to display it in a TextBox.